# How to prevent sections being treated as subsection in PDF outline

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf

I'm authoring a PDF document in latex, where the PDF outline/bookmarks are very important.

I want to have subsections and sections displayed in the navigation panel.

For some reason, each section is treated as a subsection  of the section before.

For example:

[image]

And my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[
top    = 1.4cm,
bottom = 1.4cm,
left   = 1.4cm,
right  = 1.8cm,
headheight=13.6pt,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{2.5pt}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksdepth=5, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing\section{0pt}{1.5pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}{-1pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\hypersetup{
    bookmarksnumbered=true,     
    bookmarksopen=true,         
    bookmarksopenlevel=1, 
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue
}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.7em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{first section}
so on and so forth

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{second section}
yada yada yada
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{third section}
more test text
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\section{fourth section}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\subsection{first subsection}
test test
\end{document}
```

What is causing this behavior?

Comment: Loading package `titlesec` before `hyperref` fixes the problem, if compiled on overleaf.com and opened by Adobe Reader. BTW, from the [doc of `hyperref`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), sec. 9.1.38, `hyperref` and `titlesec` are imcompatible.

Comment: Yes, that fixed it for me locally with texstudio and tested in different PDF viewers. If you want to make that the answer I will happily select it. I had no idea package order mattered.

Comment: Actually if I compile your example (without any modification) locally, with all packages updated, the PDF outline is alright. So I use overleaf.com as a uniform test benchmark.

Comment: unrelated but why do you set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` so many times

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  wanted to have sections without numbers but appearing in the PDF bookmarks/navigation tree. I had to set it before each section for it work generate correctly.

Comment: you have no code that changes its value so after the first setting to 0 it's 0 for the rest of the document and the later settings do nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer provides no extra info but some rearrangement of info in question comments.)

I cannot reproduce your problem locally (texlive 2019 with all packages updated), but on overleaf.com the problem is reproducible. Also on overleaf.com, loading package `titlesec` before `hyperref` fixes the problem (PDF is downloaded and opened with Adobe Reader). So this might be a (temporary) solution to your problem.

BTW, generally `hyperref` and `titlesec` are incompatible, by the [doc of `hyperref`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf), sec. 9.1.38.